# How to let a Unity WebGL build connect to a local python server?

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, webgl, unity-webgl

I have a python server. A unity PC client is established to connect the python server and receive data by using `System.Net`. That is, the python server will control the running of the Unity project.

Currently, we want to deploy the Unity project to the local web to make it usable to users from different platforms. What method should I use to make WebGL packaged to connect to the local python server?

----------solved-----------

Because WebGL doesn't support socket communication, the socket communication logic between the python server and the client client is changed to HTTP. `BaseHTTPServer` is used on the python server side to listen for and respond to HTTP requests. `UnityWebRequest` is used in the webGL client to send http requests to the server address.

Comment: just for understanding: You want to access the python server from where the WebGL is hosted or actually from the client devices executing it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @derHugo is it possible to access a python server with TCP in Unity WebGL builds?

Comment: @Okabe no, see [WebGL Networking](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-networking.html)

Comment: @derHugo so is there really no workaround and if yes do you have an idea how?

Comment: If your python is server side then yes you could probably just trigger a normal (e.g. php or ajax) request to your server which then can forward it to python and back

Comment: But I want to have the server to send data to my WebGL build I found this library but I dont know if it will work with this: https://github.com/endel/NativeWebSocket