# Connect to TCP server with WebGL Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, websocket, tcp, tcpserver, unity-webgl

I have a TCP server (which I can not change/modify) running which sends data and I want it to connect to Unity WebGL build.So first of all I know it is natively not supported to connect to a TCP server in WebGL. I searched for workarounds and tried the following : Use Websockify to enable connection from the TCP server to a WebSocket. I used the NativeWebsocket Library but it would not connect to the server unfortunately. I also read about these blogs :

[How to let a Unity WebGL build connect to a local python server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72123949/how-to-let-a-unity-webgl-build-connect-to-a-local-python-server)

https://forum.unity.com/threads/webgl-tcp-client.738419/

But they didn't really help either. Has anyone tried this or knows how to make it work (if it is even possible :) )?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity3D uses the .NET C# libraries, so even though Unity doesn't explicitly provide a TCP library, you can still use .NET's TCP APIs. It's worth noting that not all platforms will support this, for example, WebGL doesn't support TCP communication.

See the example in .NET documentation for help on implementation: [`System.Net.Sockets TcpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=net-6.0)

For WebGL, it is impossible to use TCP communication, so you'll have to wrap the server in some kind of HTTP/Websockets transport - you cannot leave the server as is, it will not work because the protocol cannot be communicated with for security reasons.

If you have any question as to the specifics of implementation, feel free to ask in the comments - I don't have enough information to elaborate further on your specific application

Comment: So in my case I can't change the server settings so it is not possible right? I thought that if I would use WebSockify on the hosted port from the server and create a WebSocket from that which I connect to my application but that did not work, do you know any reason for that?

Comment: If you use WebSockets to wrap a TCP server, it can potentially work - using a WebSocket API from the client would not fix the issue on its own, the restriction with TCP communication on web remains. You would need to send the server traffic through a WebSocket as a workaround, and this means the server would need to be channeled through something like websockify.

Comment: If you want advice on how to set up something like that, please provide details as to what issues you are having

Comment: from your comment I understood that without access to the server it  is not possible to connect to WebGL. So my setup is following: I have an external application  which has a TCP function that opens up on a port. I can not change this application or the server, and I have a Unity WebGL project in which I want to receive data from the application (TCP server).

Comment: As that description stands, there is no solution. There are no web APIs for directly accessing a TCP stream, for security reasons. Your only solution would be to encapsulate the TCP stream in websockets, something you would need to host on a server (either the one in question, or another one you're hosting)

Comment: Ok thx for that clarification I have to search for a different solution then